# /admin loads from http://<ww.site.com>/index.php/admin, but not from http://<www.site.com>

Tags: php, silverstripe

On ubuntu 11.10, I'm getting a 404 error when I go to http:///admin, with a corresponding error message of "File does not exist: /var/www//admin" in the apache2 error.log. The admin login DOES appear when I go to http:///index.php/admin
though.

Permissions 755, 775 or 777 get the same result.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

It seems something is wrong with pretty URLs settings.

> Friendly URLs are not working because rewriting support isn't enabled
>   on your webserver, or it's not setup correctly.
>
> Apache:
>
> 1. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled
> 2. Ensure that AllowOverride All is set for the location where SilverStripe is installed
> 3. Ensure the .htaccess file inside your SilverStripe directory has the rewrite rules setup

Can you confirm these 3 steps ?

- quoting [official support forum](http://www.silverstripe.org/installing-silverstripe/show/12446)

Comment: Duh! Had "AllowOverride" set to "None". Changing it to "All" did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveParker, if it did the trick, mark the answer as the solution!  If you don't know how or why, read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Apache Web Server, then make sure the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled and use use something like this inside an `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```